# How to compare an incoming byte from cool terminal as modbus hex value and compare it with a predefined value in set in the program?

Tags: string, float

My Input from Cool terminal is 
    05 03 00 01 00 02 94 4F

I should be able to read this input 05 03 00 01 00 02 94 4F compare with the same(05 03 00 01 00 02 94 4F). If the incoming value(05 03 00 01 00 02 94 4F) and the predefined value(05 03 00 01 00 02 94 4F) are the same it should print the hex value like

> 05 03 04 43 65 BA 7D 04 E8

I tried to code it but i could'nt get the value.
Here is my code in Arduino

```
    void setup()
    {
      Serial.begin(9600);
    }

    void loop()
    {
      static char buffer[1024];
      static size_t length = 0;

      if (Serial.available()) {
        char c = Serial.read();

        // Otherwise buffer the incoming byte.
        //else if (length < sizeof buffer - 1) {

        Serial.write(c);  // echo
        buffer[length++] = c;
      }
    }
```

Comment: You didn't include your code. And what does "couldn't get the value" mean?

Comment: Did you read what you copy & pasted? (edit question, select code, press ctrl-k to align). What means 'read this input compare with the same' ? And where is the predefined value in the code (or is the predefined value something else? If so, what exactly?

Comment: I have edited it would be good for you to understand now.

Comment: how are you determining the value to print? .... ar you doing some calculation?

Comment: @jsotola I am not doing any calculation. I just wanted to print the answer

Comment: the printed hex values are different from the input hex values ... that indicates data manipulation of some kind

Comment: Yes Yes yes !!!! The printed hex values are different because I am just printing them( and I am not mofifying anything).